# React - Cannot Read Property 'params' Of Undefined

Tags: reactjs, routes

I set params in Route. They appear in the console from my component but I get an "undefined" error.

```
<Router>
    <App>
        <Switch>
                <Route exact path='/data/:param' component={data} />
        </Switch>         
    </App>
</Router>
```

**component**

```
class Data extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

    async componentDidMount() {
        console.log(this.props.match.params.param)

    ...

export default Data;
```

If I can see them in the console why do I still get an error?

> Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'params' of undefined

[image]

Comment: Can you include the `export` line for `Data`?

Comment: I added it in. Just default export

Comment: why aren't you doing withRouter(Data) ?

Comment: You say it logs just fine, so where is the error actually happening?

Comment: I am not familiar with `withRouter(Data)` will look into it. The error occurs at the `console.log` even though I can see the params in the console. Any idea why?

Comment: `withRouter` is a HOC which injects the route props into your component. You'll need those before accessing props like so `this.props.match...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure your import is correct for the `Route` which is `Data`.

```
import Data from './Data';
...
     <Route exact path='/data/:param' component={Data} />
...
```

You don't need to wrap the component with `withRouter` higher order component since your component `Data` is already a child of `Route`.

FWIW do

```
componentDidMount() {
  console.log(this.props.match && this.props.match.params.param);
}
```

Also, you probably don't need the `async` while doing `componentDidMount()`. This also could be the reason you need to add the defensive code as given above.

PS: `console.log()` can show evaluated data which is usually represented with an `i` just besides the object eval.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am using async because of `fetch`. I posted my error picture. I believe I am importing correctly

Comment: I see your image. Did you try out the defensive code? 

So you need to check for defensive code for wherever you are trying to find anything inside `this.props.match` since the match isn't avail yet.

check which is: `this.props.match && this.props.match.params.param`

Comment: I am not familiar with defensive code. What do you mean?

Comment: use this inside your `componentDidMount`: `this.props.match && this.props.match.params.param` so you don't get an error when match is undefined - because match isn't available yet and the function is async.

Comment: Wow okay that worked! Very weird, is it because of the `async` that it wasn't working?

Comment: Congrats! Since the lifecycle method `componentDidMount()` is `async` in this case, my guess is that you see the intermediate state when the `props.match` isn't available yet. A better way to do this will be to call the `fetch()` inside `componentDidMount()` by removing `async/await` from here and updating your component _after_ the data from `fetch()` has arrived using another life-cycle method called `componentDidUpdate()`. This would mean an extra render() but it'll make sure that you don't get to see the intermediate state.

Comment: Okay great! Thanks so much for your help! Really appreciated